# Karate: How to use DB update query in karate

Tags: karate

To read we use db.readRow(Select * from tablename)

to update  record in the table when we tried to use db.executeupdate didnt worked.Can you please give me an example is there any way we can update the record using karate functions.

Comment: this is not a `karate` question. please ask someone in your team that knows Java + JDBC or ask a new question